# How quiz saves details of answered questions

Tags: android, android-file

Hi I'am currently developing an android quiz application.But I need to save the details of the questions that the user answered and want to skip those questions in between(like the logo quiz app that shows a tick mark in the questions answered).Please anyone tell me how can I implement this.

Comment: Use a sqlite database.

Comment: i was trying to save the data within the phone @AnixPasBesoin

Comment: People are down-voting you because your answer is extremely broad, and shows very little effort on your part. A good first step is to start coding up your application. Follow some tutorials online, and do some research or look up tutorials on how to make similar apps. If you are still stuck on a specific part, you can come back and ask -with code examples - about the specific parts that are troubling you.

Comment: @johnshaju An SQLite database will store the data on the phone. Myabe try reading through the developers guide on d.android.com

Comment: i completed the whole application only this part of saving details of answered questions is left so please suggest me some method kindly @AnixPasBesoin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the SharedPreferences.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html